# Sed wildcard replace

Tags: replace, sed, wildcard

I am not sure why I am having a hard time with this, I have this SQL file:

```
insert into table_name values ('Danny:2:1429543183', 195621, 'My  Stuff', '', 'Fake', '', '', 0, 1429553870, 1429543183, 1429543183, 1429543183, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 'P', 195621, '', '', 0, 0, '', 0, 1429543183, 0, '', '', 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 1);
```

I want to change every thing that starts with `142*` to a new value.

```
sed 's:\(142.*).*\,/\1 93284209348\g' /tmp/1 --> Nope
sed "s/[, 142*,]/ 93284209348,/"g /tmp/1 --> Changes everything to 93284209348
```

I think I'm getting a headache :)

Comment: Can you expand on Nope? Does nothing happen?

Comment: ‘*starts with `142*`*’ And ends with...?

Comment: `sed 's/\:142[0-9]\{1,\}/:93284209348/g' /tmp/1`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
sed 's/\([ :]\)142[0-9]*/\193284209348/g' file
insert into table_name values ('Danny:2:93284209348', 195621, 'My  Stuff', '', 'Fake', '', '', 0, 93284209348, 93284209348, 93284209348, 93284209348, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 'P', 195621, '', '', 0, 0, '', 0, 93284209348, 0, '', '', 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 1);
```

Edit: fixed so that the first number has correct start `:` and other uses space.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<142[0-9]*/93284209348/g' file
```